# Debug Flutter web app in VS Code without creating a Microsoft Edge new instance

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge, flutter-web

everything is set up and working but when I start debugging flutter in vs code using microsoft edge it starts a new instance , meaning the browser data, password, settings .... are all reset, so i need to enter passwords and change settings every time i start debugging or i need to open two browser instances which is both resources intensive and clingy.
is there like vs code configuration for flutter that works as "attach" to an existing browser instance instead of "launch" a new instance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to run with following command,

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0
```

then access `http://<your-ip> or localhost:8080`

with this you can open your flutter web-app in regular browser and also you can open it in other devices in network(with your ip)
** also you should ensure that your port(8080) is open.

Comment: This is working but with every change you need to save and type r for hot reload or R for hot restart to see the changes and then refresh the web page , isn't there a launch.json config that will work just like the default debugging of dart in vs code ,but in an already running browser , that will reload and display changes with saving the chances in the vs code

Comment: i don't think it's possible because we are running web as web-server so

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a perfect solution, as this one requires you to install the `Dart Debug Extension`, but you can create a `launch.json` and paste this command:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter Web Project",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "args": [
                "-d",
                "web-server"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This still opens a new browser instance everytime I start a debug session. Is there a way to just open a new tab in an existing browser instance?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution misses the feature of auto reload in VS Code. You will have to input `r` in terminal for refreshing. You can follow these steps to configure VS Code to always start flutter web in the same port.

1. Go to settings
2. Search for `Dart: Flutter Run Additional Args`
3. Enter `--web-port=1234`
4. Click `Add Item`

[image: VS Code setting to set up flutter web port]

Answer (score -1):

Normally, if Microsoft Edge is already running when you start debugging with a launch config, then the new instance won't start in remote debugging mode.

So by default, the extension launches Microsoft Edge with a separate user profile in a temp folder. Use `userDataDir` to set a different path to use, or set to false to launch with your default user profile.

A simple example:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Microsoft Edge",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "edge",
            "url": "...\\Index.html", // Provide your project's url to finish configuring
            "userDataDir": false // You could also add ${local_app_data}\Edge\Profile, such as C:\Users\<Current-user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\Profile
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: it's not working + I don't think that's for flutter/dart apps

Comment: How do you debug it using Edge? Did you use the `Debugger for Microsoft Edge` Tool in VS Code? If this is the case, you could refer to [related doc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-edge).

Comment: I have the extension installed but i'm debugging flutter the normal way, i have the dart debug extension installed in microsoft edge tho from the chrome extension store